# Increase the intensity of certain part of frame using opencv

Tags: c, image, image-processing, opencv

Suppose there is a frame with some image.I want to display only those parts which have pixel intensity above 120 or 130. How can I do that with OpenCv ? Is there any commands to do so?
Then i need to set those parts to some intensity of 190.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by astay13, you can use the [threshold](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#double%20threshold%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20double%20thresh,%20double%20maxVal,%20int%20thresholdType%29) function like this:

```
Mat image = imread("someimage.jpg", 0); // flag == 0 means read as grayscale
Mat mask;

// this tells you where locations >= 120 pixel intensity are
threshold(image, mask, 120.0, 255.0, THRESH_BINARY); 

// this sets those locations to 190 based on the mask you just created
image.setTo(Scalar(190, 0, 0), mask);
imshow("image", image);
```

Hope that is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [cvThreshold](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html?highlight=thresh#cvThreshold) function.  For the second part, [cvFloodFill](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html?highlight=thresh#floodfill) might be what you need.